# Checking multiple .csv file exist or not from folder

Tags: powershell, batch, csv

We have a requirement needed to be checked and ensure multiple files start with number(s) in their name with .csv files in a folder. If yes then will proceed with further steps. If any of the files are missing then send an email to business along with missing file names. Is that achievable from a batch script or PowerShell?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the script, though test it first in a duplicate folder. It is untested since I don't have the file(names)

```
# Define the folder path
$folderPath = "C:\Where\All\CSVs\Are"

# Get a list of all CSV files in the folder
$csvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Filter "*.csv"

# Initialize variables for tracking sequence and missing files
$expectedNumber = 1
$missingFiles = @()

# Loop through each CSV file
foreach ($csvFile in $csvFiles) {
    # Get the base name of the file without extension
    $baseName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($csvFile.Name)
    
    # Check if the base name starts with the expected number
    if ($baseName -match "^$expectedNumber") {
        $expectedNumber++
    } else {
        $missingFiles += $csvFile.Name
    }
}

if ($missingFiles.Count -gt 0) {
    Write-Host "Missing Files:"
    foreach ($missingFile in $missingFiles) {
        Write-Host $missingFile
    }

    # Convert the list of missing files to a string
    $missingFilesString = $missingFiles -join "`r`n"

    # Email configuration
    $emailParams = @{
        SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
        Port = 587
        UseSsl = $true
        Credential = Get-Credential
        From = "your-email@gmail.com"
        To = "recipient@example.com"
        Subject = "Missing CSV Files"
        Body = "The following CSV files are missing or out of sequence:`r`n`r`n$missingFilesString"
    }

    # Send the email
    Send-MailMessage @emailParams
} else {
    Write-Host "All CSV files have names starting with numbers in sequence."
}
```

This script will ask you for your credentials. I suggest creating an App password for this script and use that in place of credentials

EDIT:
Seems like OP wants to store credentials in an external encrypted file. I will suggest to create an [app password](https://www.lifewire.com/get-a-password-to-access-gmail-by-pop-imap-2-1171882) specifically for this script, and use that inplace of your google account password.

First, you need to create that XML file using this PS script:

```
$credential = Get-Credential

$credential | Export-CliXml -Path "C:\Where\To \Save\The\Credentials\myCred_${env:USERNAME}_${env:COMPUTERNAME}.xml"
```

NOTE: you don't need to edit the USERNAME and COMPUTERNAME, they are set automatically. And you need to remember that this encrypted XML file is SPECIFIC to your **user** and your **machine** both. Which means if you try to load the XML on a different computer or with a different user, it will **not** work. If you want to be able to run the script on a different machine, you have no other choice but to store password in plain text.

And the, here's the main script for that usecase

```
# Define the folder path
$folderPath = "C:\Where\All\CSVs\Are"

# Get a list of all CSV files in the folder
$csvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Filter "*.csv"

# Initialize variables for tracking sequence and missing files
$expectedNumber = 1
$missingFiles = @()

# Loop through each CSV file
foreach ($csvFile in $csvFiles) {
    # Get the base name of the file without extension
    $baseName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($csvFile.Name)
    
    # Check if the base name starts with the expected number
    if ($baseName -match "^$expectedNumber") {
        $expectedNumber++
    } else {
        $missingFiles += $csvFile.Name
    }
}

if ($missingFiles.Count -gt 0) {
    Write-Host "Missing Files:"
    foreach ($missingFile in $missingFiles) {
        Write-Host $missingFile
    }

    # Convert the list of missing files to a string
    $missingFilesString = $missingFiles -join "`r`n"

    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString "MyPlainTextAppSpecificPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
    $cred = Import-CliXml -Path "C:\Where\To \Save\The\Credentials\myCred_${env:USERNAME}_${env:COMPUTERNAME}.xml"
    # Email configuration
    $emailParams = @{
        SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
        Port = 587
        UseSsl = $true
        Credential = $cred
        From = "your-email@gmail.com"
        To = "recipient@example.com"
        Subject = "Missing CSV Files"
        Body = "The following CSV files are missing or out of sequence:`r`n`r`n$missingFilesString"
    }

    # Send the email
    Send-MailMessage @emailParams
} else {
    Write-Host "All CSV files have names starting with numbers in sequence."
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. My file names are start with Alphanumeric example here : 1a. analysis of change Non PAA_PY.csv,1a. analysis of change Non PAA_CY.csv, 1b. analysis of change Non PAA_PY.csv,1b. analysis of change PAA_CY.csv and 2.Statement of PLC.csv.

Comment: Any possibilities instead of asking user name and password any alternative solutions to be mentioned in the script itself.?

Comment: Any updates please?

Comment: KIndly use `code blocks` when stating things like filenames to make then stand out using  ` around the words. If they start with alphanumeric, how are you going to know if `1b` is the last one, i.e. `1c` is not a missing file, and why are they missing. If possible, edit you question with a list of sample file names to make it clear

Comment: Yes you can hardcode your account CREDENTIALS in the script itself, which is NOT the safest approach. Though if you really want to, I will update my answer

Comment: Here it's sample files 
•1a.Analysis of change non PAA report_CY.csv
•1a.Analysis of change non PAA report_PY.csv
•1b.Analysis of change PAA report_CY.csv
•1b. Analysis of change PAA report_PY.csv
•2.Statement of PL-OCI-report
•Impact of contracts recognized in the year-report.csv
Our mail requirement if file exist will do further steps else send notification email to business with missing files. Also, while sending email notification instead of asking credential any possibility PS scripts support and pick the password stored in some folder that path can be mentioned in the PS script?

Comment: Above both script only consider file name start with number only this is not expected. one. our requirement is need to be checked file name start with alpha numeric and Non alpha numeric and number with .csv files.

Comment: You have still not understood my question. How can I know the correct sequence and whether `b` is the last letter for `1` or there are no letters in `2`. I can see `1b` two times. Handling alphanumeric naming is not possible unless you know how many letters each number will have. In your original question you stated the requirements for numbers only

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Is there any possibilities for script-If File name start with numeric even multiple file names start with same but entire file name is different for .csv files that can be consider as file exist and if no numeric that can be consider as does not exist. example the few following files exist and same format start from 2 as well.
•1. Analysis of change non PAA report_CY.csv
•1. Analysis of change non PAA report_PY.csv
•1. Analysis of change PAA report_CY.csv
•1. Analysis of change PAA report_PY.csv
I

Comment: Instead of asking credential while sending email any alternative solutions to store password in folder and mentioned that path in the script.

Comment: So you basically want `non PPA CY`, `non PPA PY`, `PPA CY`, and `PPA PY` for every consecutive number starting from 1. Clear this first. And if any of the four are missing, email their _expected_ filenames, Right?

Comment: Yes, you can store your credentials in a `xml`file, and retrieve credentials from that file, updating answer

Comment: Below are file names o1a. Analysis of change non PAA report_CY.csv
o1a. Analysis of change non PAA report_PY.csv
o1b. Analysis of change PAA report_CY.csv
o1b. Analysis of change PAA report_PY.csv
o2.statement.csv
o3.statement of FPOS.csv
o4.insureance service.csv
o5.Insurance finance.csv
o6a.Recon LRC_LIC_CY.csv
o\6a.Recon LRC_LIC_PY.csv
o8a.Recon Measurement.Cy.csv
o8a.Recon Measurement.PY.csv
o Contract of impacts.csv
If any the file name missing send out email else will do further steps. as per my knowledge we can check file start with number would be exist else does not exist

Comment: You are clearly rotating facts. Are there only these 12 you want to be checked? They don't even follow sequential numbering, and the last one doesn't starts with a number. They clearly have no clear pattern. I am sorry if I am not able to understand what are you trying to say